# Solving stochastic control problems using Hitsuda representation

Tags: finance, stochastic-analysis, optimal-control

I would like to solve the following problem.
Consider a financial market with quadratic transaction costs, one risky asset with price dynamics:
$S_t = s_0 + \mu t + \sigma W_t$,  for $t \geq 0 , \sigma > 0, \mu \in {R}$ and $W$ is Brownian Motion. 
and (for simplicity) let the riskless asset bearing zero interest.

Now consider a risk neutral trader having access to the Filtration
$ G_t^{\Delta} := F_{t+\Delta}^S$, for ${\Delta} \in [0,\infty)$,
so he has more information than just having acces to the augmented filtration $(F_t^S)_{t \geq 0}$

I then tried to calculate the Valuefunction V for a timehorizon $T>0$, which led me to 
$V_T^{\Phi_0, \phi} = \Phi_0 (S_T - S_0) + \int_0^T \phi_t(S_T-S_t)dt - \frac{\Lambda}{2} \int_0^T \phi_t^2 dt$ ,
where $\Phi_0$ is my position at the Start, $\phi$ is my traiding strategy and the last term is the quadratic transaction costs for a $\Lambda > 0$.

Since the trader is risk neutral we have a linear utility function i.e. u(x) = x
Also we need that $\phi$ is an admissible trading strategy, hence $G^\Delta$-optional with $\int_0^T \phi_t^2 < \infty$

I then tried to calculate:
$max_{\phi} E[u(V_T^{\Phi_0, \phi})] = max_{\phi} E[V_T^{\Phi_0, \phi}]$

After using tower property and other properties this led to:
$max_{\phi}( \Phi_0(\mu T -s_0) + \int_0^T \mu (T-t) E[\phi_t] + \sigma E[\phi_t (W_{t+\Delta} - W_t)] - \frac{\Lambda}{2} E[\phi_t^2] dt)$

And here i am stuck tried to solve it using the Hitsuda represantion but i dont how to start.

Since i am very interested in the process of how to solve such a problem or related problems i would really like to just get a hint (not a whole solution) if someone has a idea where and how to start or maybe someone knows good lecture to unterstand the process of working with the hitsuda representation.

Comment: Shouldn't the terminal wealth be something like $W_T=\int_0^{T}\phi_tdS_t+W_0$ assuming $\phi_t$ is the number of shares held at time $t$ (-transaction costs).

Comment: I did the following:
I started using $dV_T = \Phi_T dS_T$, with $\Phi_T = \Phi_0 + \int_0^T \phi_t dt$
then i got:
$dV_T = \Phi_T dS_T = (\Phi_0 + \int_0^T \phi_t dt)(S_T - S_0) = \Phi_0 (S_T - S_0) + \int_0^T \phi_t dt(S_T-S_0) = \Phi_0 (S_T - S_0) + \int_0^T \phi_t(S_T-S_t)dt$
 and then i did the same for the problem with friction: 
I started with $dV_T = \Phi_T dS_T - c_T dT$, for $c(t) = \frac{\Lambda}{2} \phi_t^2$
 which if im not wrong is the same just with the term: $-\frac{\Lambda}{2}\int_0^T \phi_t^2 dt $ at the end

or have i done something wrong ?

Comment: Why would $dV_T=\Phi_T dS_T$ hold?

Comment: It holds by definition

Comment: But isn't $T$ a fixed terminal date?

Comment: $T > 0$ is a fixed Timehorizon

Comment: What is the precise meaning of $V_T$? Is it terminal wealth? If so $dV_T$ does not make sense because $T$ does not move in time. Or is it the expected terminal wealth at some time point? Please define it in your question.

Comment: i thought of $V_T$ as the profits and losses from trading up to T.
okay so what if we don't fix a time horizon T, and just say T > 0  and moves in time then $dV_T$ does make sense right ? 

Im sorry i still have some problems  using the notation... in the lecture we had $dV_T = V_T - V_0$

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the solution would look like in the standard non-anticipating case. Define the wealth at time $t$ as $Y_t$. This evolves as

$$dY_t=\int_o^t\phi_sdsdS_t-\frac{\Lambda}{2}\phi_t^2dt$$

Hence at terminal date $T$

$$Y_T=\int_0^{T}\int_o^t\phi_sdsdS_t-\int_0^{T}\frac{\Lambda}{2}\phi_t^2dt+Y_0$$

You can normalize $Y_0=0$. You have

$$E(Y_T)=\int_0^{T}\int_0^t\phi_sds\mu dt-\int_0^{T}\frac{\Lambda}{2}\phi_t^2dt=\int_0^{T}(\int_0^t\phi_sds\mu-\frac{\Lambda}{2}\phi_t^2) dt$$

The problem is

$$\max_{\phi_t}E(Y_T)$$

The first order condition is

$$\mu-\Lambda \phi_t=0$$

and hence

$$\phi_t=\frac{\mu}{\Lambda}$$